# What is the impulse response of the system with this difference equation:

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

The difference equation is written:

$$y(k)-\frac{5}{12}y(k-1)+\frac{1}{24}y(k-2)=x(k)-\frac{1}{2}x(k-1) $$

The system is linear, invariant and causal.
For $x(k)=δ(k)$, the equation will be:
$$g(k)-\frac{5}{12}g(k-1)+\frac{1}{24}g(k-2)=δ(k)-\frac{1}{2}δ(k-1)$$

I calculated $g(0)=1$, $g(1)= -\frac{1}{12}$, $g(2)= -\frac{11}{144}$ and $g(3)= -\frac{49}{1728}$ but i can't find any relation between them.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the $Z$-transform?

Comment: As pointed out by @Matt L., you can follow the procedure using the $Z$-transform, as detailed in the great source https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Z_Transform_Difference_Equations.html

Comment: Doesn't say i can use Z trasform, but if it works and can provide me with the right answer, i guess i can

Comment: Since this is not forbidden, I gave you the first steps in an anwser. Once you have the formula, you can test its corrected with the coefficients you have already computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the difference equation
$$y(k)−\frac{5}{12}y(k−1)+\frac{1}{24}y(k−2)=x(k)−\frac{1}{2}x(k−1),$$
you can express the $Z$-transform on both sides ($X(Z)$ and $Y(Z)$ denote the $Z$-transforms of $x$ and $y$) and get:
$$Y(Z)\left(1−\frac{5}{12}Z^{-1}+\frac{1}{24}Z^{-2}\right)=X(Z)\left(1−\frac{1}{2}Z^{-1}\right).$$

Details on this procedure are quite well explained in [$Z$ Transform of Difference Equations](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Z_Transform_Difference_Equations.html).

The transfert function $H(Z)$ is given by the ratio of the output by the input:
$$H(Z) = Y(Z)/X(Z) = \frac{1−\frac{1}{2}Z^{-1}}{1−\frac{5}{12}Z^{-1}+\frac{1}{24}Z^{-2}}.$$
As the denominator is (now) a simple polynomial of degree 2 in $Z^{-1}$, you can quite easily expand the rational fraction $H(Z)$ in $Z^{-1}$ to obtain a series $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} h(k)Z^{-k}$ by using formal expressions like:
$$\frac{1}{1-X} = 1+X^{-1}+X^{-2}\ldots$$
and
$$\frac{1}{1+aX+bX^2} = c/(X-r_0)+d/(X-r_1)$$
with $r_0$ and $r_1$ the roots of the degree-2 polynomial $1+aX+bX^2$.

With some computations with the numerator, you should be able to retrieve the solution to your expression, with simple formulas for your $h(k)$, providing you with the impulse response you have looking for.

You can find additional material in [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). If you prefer a more self-contained, note-like document, I would suggest the following [Difference equation solutions from impulse response](http://www.ece.utah.edu/eceCTools/DSP/CToolsDiscImpSoln.htm), which provides an alternative explanation.

Comment: I think that y(z)/x(z)=(1-(1/2)z^ -1) / (1-(5/12)z^-1+(1/24)z^ -2)

Comment: Laurent, you've got numerator and denominator mixed up in your formula for $H(z)$.

Comment: My mistake, I corrected them, and added some additional details to cope with degree-2 polynomials at the denominator.

Comment: I found H(z)= -72/(z-(1/4)) + 96/(z-(1/6)) How do i find h(k)?

Comment: Follow the steps given in the paragraph "As the denominator\ldots", expand your $c/(Z-r_0)$ as infinite power series.

Comment: OK: suppose $H(z) = \frac{1}{2-z}$. Then $$H(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{1-z/2}\right) =  \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + (z/2)^1+ (z/2)^2 + \dots\right).$$ You should do that for your two terms, combine the same powers in $z$, and you should be on the right track. My goal, as you guess, is to help you do the job by yourself, not do the calculations.

Comment: I came up to this: H(z)= -72(1/z +1/(4(z^2))+1/(16(z^3))+.....)  + 96(1/z+ 1/(6(z^2))+1/(36(z^3))+....)                                                                      Does this mean that h(k)= -72(4^(1-n)) +96(6^(1-n))

Comment: No quite, you should keep on with the $z^{-1}$. On my side I get $h(k) = 4/6^k-3/4^k$. It seems to match with your first calculations.

Comment: What did you do with the constants -72 and 96? Why don't they appear in your answer?

Comment: If my answer is correct, which you can check first, then they disappear because they simplify.